# Help identifying the Paperless Post logo font

Tags: font-identification

I've tried to ID this font, using [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/), but have had no luck.  I also did a Google search, trying to find it myself, with the same result.

I know that script fonts can be a little tricky, with that service, so I went in and manually spaced the letters so they could more easily be identified.

My search returned a couple fonts that *almost* looked like this one, but nothing close enough.

[image: logo]

I only want the font used for "Paperless" and not "Post" beneath it.

Thanks!

Comment: To avoid duplicates and to see what's *not* good enough: please list some of the alternatives that you rejected.

Comment: @RadLexus I have no idea what I did differently this time, in separating the letters, but I must have done it slightly different than the first time and now I can't find the same fonts

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to Alin's answer, I was able to get in touch with Jessica Karle, the Lead Product Designer at Paperless Post.

Jessica informed me that **the font was a custom design** by Louise Fili (http://www.louisefili.com/).

Answer (score 5):

In an announcement made by [Jessica Karle](http://www.jessicakarle.com/paperless-post/), the Lead Product Designer from Paperless Post when redesigning the online experience she states *"We are a group of designers from all disciplines—fine art, graphic design, product design, UX/UI, and branding."*

Also, looking at [her work](http://www.jessicakarle.com/work/) she designed some lettering logos. Taking that and adding it to the statement above and the fact that we can't identify the font anywhere I think we can assume that the font was designed especially by/for them.

It's not that common but if you think about the team they have, how long do you think it would take them during a brainstorming for one of them to say "***Wouldn't it be great if we took the time and designed our own font?***".

Also, searching on [Justia Trademarks](https://trademarks.justia.com) for Paperless Post registration you will get the [PAPERLESS POST - Trademark Details](https://trademarks.justia.com/855/76/paperless-post-85576921.html) which at the **Mark Drawing** section has **3000 - Illustration: Drawing or design which also includes word(s)/ letter(s)/number(s) Typeset**

Comment: Good point, but I'd argue that it actually is pretty common.

Comment: @CAI Well, not where I live so I guess it depends. I know only a handfull of companies that invested in designing their own font.

Comment: Also there is a difference between designing a logotype from scratch (i.e not based on a font) and designing a whole font. A company designing their own font probably isn't common, but generally speaking, designing a logotype from scratch I'm sure is very common.

Comment: The thought of it being custom did cross my mind.  I found two in WTF that were pretty similar, so maybe they based their own font on one of those.  Thanks.

Comment: @JohnManly You are welcome! Sorry my answer isn't more documented but there isn't more to find about it. Have a great day and good luck.